# Which version of Windows and Visual Studio do i need to download for building Windows 8 Phone apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

I have purchased `Windows 8.1 pro` and downloaded `Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone`.
But when I try to run a simple app in the emulator but it says You need to Update Visual Studio Express 2012 to update 3 since it has some compatibility issues,i have downloaded the ISO file from the below link.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305

But when I try to install I get these errors:

What is the issue here ?

Setup Failed

1)  The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

2)       The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider.

So how to solve this issue here ?

Comment: What did google tell you about these errors?

Comment: I am not able to find any help for this

Comment: I am not able to use the emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Windows 8.1 apps you should install Visual Studios 2013.

Comment: I am working on Windows phone apps and not desktop apps, so which VS do I need to download ?

Comment: and what is the difference Visual Studio Express 2012 for Phone and Visual Studio pro ?